# Not getting any tokens for users section in apps.ionic.io dashboard

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

Now I am working with push notification with the help of the below reference url.

- https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/
- [Ionic Push to specific user from Ionic.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152784/ionic-push-to-specific-user-from-ionic-io)

In this the users are registered but it's showing message like this "user has no push token registered."

Here by I attached the image url for better understanding.

- http://postimg.org/image/9qrnnc85n/

  ```
    function IonicPushInit(){
          var push = new Ionic.Push({
              "debug": true
          });
          var callback = function(token) {
              push.saveToken(token);
          }
          push.register(callback);
      }

      function IonicIoLogin(){
          var user = Ionic.User.current();

          if (user.isAuthenticated()) {
              IonicPushInit();

          } else {
              var details = {
                  'name':  'anandh',
                  'email':  'something@gmmail.com',
                  'password': 'secretpassword'
              };

              details.custom = {
                  'wants_emails': true,
                  'favoriteColor': 'blue',
                  'website': 'http://ionic.io'
              };

              var options = { 'remember': true };

              Ionic.Auth.login('basic', options, details).then(function(suc){
                  IonicPushInit();
              }, function(err){
                  Ionic.Auth.signup(details).then(function(s){
                      IonicPushInit();
                  }, function(e){
                      alert(e);
                  });
              });
          }
      }
      IonicIoLogin();
  ```

Any one can explain clearly how to get device token for users, it would be helpful to me. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: No doubt that devdactic blog is great. But you should the official docs too http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-quick-start. It might help you

Comment: ofcourse  @Atula is right

Comment: You can see that blog in that he is also not using any device token in-order to get push notification .

Comment: In that blog we need DEVICE_TOKEN, PROFILE_NAME, API_TOKEN in order to send push notifications using postman